# Prevent React component re render when route change

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, react-component

I am using react-router-dom.

let's assume I have 2 pages like Homepage and Profile Page. Both pages have a component named a Header.

In the Header component, using useEffect React Hook I am calling a fetch request on my back-end server and fetching logged-in user data. API returns username, avatar image, etc. (that's not a problem)

thing is that. when I jump from "Homepage" to "profile page", the Header component, re-render and send the request to the server again. this occurs every time when I jump from the homepage to the profile page or profile page to the home page. and the data displayed on the Header keeps loading until the fetched request succeeds.

I want something like Youtube.

> Header Component

```
import {useState , useEffect} from 'react'

import Logo from './imgs/logo.png'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import { FaArrowRight , FaServicestack , FaFirstOrder} from "react-icons/fa";
import { BsPersonCheck , AiOutlineContacts } from "react-icons/all";


const ShowOrHideNav = ()=>{
    var nav = document.getElementById('NavBarSpingbuck')
    nav.classList.toggle('hidden')
}


const Header = () =>{
    const [loggedIn , setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
    const [user_data , setUserData] = useState(undefined)

    const Logout = () =>{
        localStorage.removeItem('sb_auth_token')
        UpdateHeader()
    }

    const UpdateHeader = () =>{
        const auth_token = localStorage.getItem('sb_auth_token')
        if(auth_token){
            console.log('sending request')
            fetch(
                'https://dummy_API_URL.dummy_domain.com/authentication/user/',
                {
                    headers:{
                        Authorization : 'Token ' + auth_token,
                    },
                }
            )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(resp_data =>{
                if(resp_data.status == 200){
                    setUserData(resp_data.data)
                }
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log(error)
                console.log('error')
            })
            setLoggedIn(true)
        }
        else{
            setLoggedIn(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        UpdateHeader()
        
    } , [])
    return(
        <div className=' fixed top-0 z-50 w-full shadow bg-black bg-opacity-75 px-5' style={{backdropFilter:'blur(18px)'}}>
            <div className='container py-2 flex items-center justify-between mx-auto relative'>
                <div className='w-8 h-8 md:hidden flex flex-col justify-evenly items-end cursor-pointer group ' onClick={ShowOrHideNav}>
                    <span className='w-2 h-1 bg-white block rounded-full transition-all delay-150 duration-300 group-hover:w-8'></span>
                    <span className='w-4 h-1 bg-white block rounded-full transition-all duration-300 group-hover:w-8'></span>
                    <span className='w-8 h-1 bg-white block rounded-full '></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Link to='/'>
                        <img src={Logo} className='w-32 ' />
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className='px-5'>
                    <ul className='items-center hidden p-4 md:p-0 md:flex absolute md:relative top-full md:top-0 w-full md:w-auto z-50 left-0 bg-white md:bg-transparent rounded-lg md:rounded-none transition-all duration-300' style={{animationIterationCount:1}} id='NavBarSpingbuck'>
                        <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-150 transform px-4 mb-4 md:mb-0' >
                            <Link className='flex flex-col items-center text-gray-800 md:text-white'>
                                <p>Jobs</p>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-150 transform px-4 mb-4 md:mb-0' >
                            <Link className='flex flex-col items-center text-gray-800 md:text-white'>
                                <p>Services</p>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-150 transform px-4 mb-4 md:mb-0' >
                            <Link className='flex flex-col items-center text-gray-800 md:text-white'>
                                <p>Place Order</p>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-150 transform px-4 mb-4 md:mb-0' >
                            <Link className='flex flex-col items-center text-gray-800 md:text-white'>
                                <p>About</p>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-150 transform px-4 mb-4 md:mb-0' >
                            <Link className='flex flex-col items-center text-gray-800 md:text-white'>
                                <p>Contact</p>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='account_bar'>
                    {
                        loggedIn?
                        <div className='flex items-center cursor-pointer group relative py-1'>
                            <div className='mr-3 rounded-full w-10 h-10 bg-center bg-cover' style={{backgroundImage:'url(https://pixinvent.com/materialize-material-design-admin-template/app-assets/images/user/12.jpg)'}}>
    
                            </div>
                            {
                                user_data && user_data.username ?
                                <p className='text-white'>{user_data.username}</p>: <p className='text-white'>User</p>

                            }
                            <div className='bg-white rounded-md py-2 w-28 absolute top-full shadow-2xl hidden group-hover:block'>
                                <ul>
                                    <li className='px-2 py-1 hover:bg-blue-100'>
                                        <Link className='block' to='/profile/' >Profile</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className='px-2 py-1 hover:bg-blue-100' onClick={()=>{Logout()}}>
                                        Logout
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            

                        :
                        <Link to='/authentication/login/' >
                            <div className='bg-yellow-600 py-0.5 px-2 rounded flex items-center justify-center hover:bg-yellow-700 transition-all duration-300'>
                                <p className='text-white pr-1'>Sign in</p>
                                <FaArrowRight className='text-white text-sm' />
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    }
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 3):

You can render your `Header` component on its own route, separate from the route rendering either the home or profile pages. Use an array of paths you want the header component's `Route` to match. Presuming "/" is your homepage then you may also want to specify the `exact` prop so "/" doesn't match ***every*** path you have. This all, of course, also assumes the header component is rendered before all other content on the page for each of the home and profile pages.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path={["/profile", "/"]} component={Header} />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
    <Route path="/" component={HomePage" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question, But it not solved my problem. [link]https://springbuck.herokuapp.com/), here is the link to my site. Please have a look with these credentials. e-mail = dummy@gmail.com and password = dummy

Comment: When you log in, please navigate between the homepage and profile page. (Profile page link found when you hover avatar ), Please notice header behaviour specially header right section

Comment: @ZeevhYOrg. I feel confident this solution works in general, and should get you close to what you are looking for. Can you update your question to include the [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it's easier to see what you're working with?

Comment: I updated the question with the Header component Code. Hope this will helpful to understand,

Comment: @ZeevhYOrg. Honestly the more important code is *where/what* is rendering the `Header` component as this is what is mounting/remounting it.

Comment: Hello, Your official answer works now. Thanks for helping me out. Very grateful to you

Answer (score 3):

Extract the `Header` component and place it on the same level with the `Switch` component.

```xml
<Router>
  <Header />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/profile">
      <Profile />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```